# MVC3 date Picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

I am trying to implement an MVC3 DatePicker but having trouble.  I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    /// <reference path="jquery-1.5.1.js" />/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" />
    $(document).ready(function () {    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});});


</script>

<div>

    @Html.TextBox("SRRDate", Model.SRRDate.ToString(), new { @class = "date" })

    Start Date

</div>
```

However, I am getting an "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method" in jquery-1.5.1-min.js

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you including both jQuery and jQuery UI files?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@Russ....thanks for the assistance.  I found the issue.  I had a Telerik scritp Registrar which was included in the _Layout.cshtml.  That was causing the error.  I imagine the Telerik js files are old.  When I look at their documentation, their code is using MVC2 style

Answer (score 4):

Are you referencing the jQuery script and a jQuery UI script that contains the datepicker plugin? Both script references should appear before your block of code.

The `/// <reference path="jquery-1.5.1.js" />` lines are references for providing intellisense for JavaScript and should go in the relevant script i.e. in this case, this should reference the `.vsdoc` version of the jQuery script and go at the top of the jQuery script file.

In summary, the layout should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.11.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function () {    $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"});});   
</script>
```

Comment: The error is *unlikely* to be in the jQuery script. The error may manifest as coming from jQuery, but it's more likely to be a problem with other code. What browser are you running it in (looks like IE)? Are you using any other scripts in the page?

Comment: @Russ..yeap, IE 7...and there other scripts in the page

Comment: Are you using jQuery validation? There was an issue with the rewrite of `$.ajax` (using the new `$.Deferred` object under the hood) and jQuery validation 1.7. Do you get the issue in other browsers?

Comment: @Russ...let me check the other browsers.  I did figure out that it's a conflict.  When I remove all the default js files that the .Net MVC3 app includes and then include:

Comment: @russ...the correct js files it works....see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144736/using-the-jquery-datepicker-in-asp-net-mvc3-projects

Comment: @MikeTWebb: I'd start by removing all scripts except your script block, jQuery and jQuery-UI. If no error, add another script. Keep going until the error manifests itself. If the error is happening cross-browser, then use another browser that has better debugging tools to track it down e.g. Firefox with Firebug. This will help in tracking it down more quickly. Hope that helps!